# Set environment's parameter the first cell of the table

Tags: tables, environments, cell

I need to create new table environment where fist cell(1row & 1column) would be set as parameter of my environment for example

```
\begin{environment}{first box data}
& Its information \\
\end{environment}
```

> I think it will be something like this

```
\newenvironment{environment}[1]
    {\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{l|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
    #1 ....
    }
    { 
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}
    }
```

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: If you replace `...` in your code snippet by `&`, your code should work as expected. Although I can not see any advantage in comparison to setting up the table as usual.

Comment: I need to have two columns but when i am setting & after #1 I get new empty column added after it and then "Its information" cell. But if I do not put anything after #1 my text in second cell do not ends as expected. And it is not needed to put & before information cell when using environment
I will attach the image in Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're aiming at:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for dummy contents

\newenvironment{environment}[1]
  {\center\tabularx{\columnwidth}{@{}l|X@{}} #1 &}
  {\endtabularx\endcenter}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{environment}{Something}
\lipsum[3]
\end{environment}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]